# Declaration 'subscribe' cannot override more than one superclass declaration (ReSwift)

Tags: ios, swift, reswift

I'm having a problem when overriding a function from the ReSwift Pod. I've got the following mock class:

```
import Foundation
import Quick
import Nimble
import RxSwift
@testable import MainProject
@testable import ReSwift

    class MockReSwiftStore: ReSwift.Store<MainState> {
    var dispatchDidRun: Bool = false
    var subscribeWasTriggered: Bool = false

    init() {
        let reducer: Reducer<MainState> = {_, _  in MainState() }
        super.init(reducer: reducer, state: nil)
    }

    required init(
        reducer: @escaping (Action, State?) -> State,
        state: State?,
        middleware: [(@escaping DispatchFunction, @escaping () -> State?) -> (@escaping DispatchFunction) -> DispatchFunction]) {
        super.init(reducer: reducer, state: state, middleware: middleware)
    }

    override func subscribe<SelectedState, S>(
        _ subscriber: S,
        transform: ((Subscription<MainState>) -> Subscription<SelectedState>)?)
        where S: StoreSubscriber,

        S.StoreSubscriberStateType == SelectedState {
            subscribeWasTriggered = true
        }
    }
}
```

And when overriding the subscribe method I'm getting following errors

[image]

Then when using autocomplete it also shows 2 occurences:
[image]

However when looking for the original function there's only one which looks like this

```
open func subscribe<SelectedState, S: StoreSubscriber>(
    _ subscriber: S, transform: ((Subscription<State>) -> Subscription<SelectedState>)?
) where S.StoreSubscriberStateType == SelectedState
{
    // Create a subscription for the new subscriber.
    let originalSubscription = Subscription<State>()
    // Call the optional transformation closure. This allows callers to modify
    // the subscription, e.g. in order to subselect parts of the store's state.
    let transformedSubscription = transform?(originalSubscription)

    _subscribe(subscriber, originalSubscription: originalSubscription,
               transformedSubscription: transformedSubscription)
}
```

This is my compiler output 
[image]

I'm out of ideas so any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
class Some<T> {

    func echo() {
        print("A")
    }

}

extension Some where T: Equatable {

    func echo() {
        print("B")
    }

}


class AnotherSome: Some<String> {

    override func echo() {
        print("Doesn't compile")
    }

}
```

The problem is: ReSwift developers declare `Store.subscribe` behavior as a part of interface and as a part of extension (I am not sure why they chose to do it instead of introducing other objects). Swift can't figure out which part you are trying to override and thus it doesn't compile. Afaik there are no language instruments which allow you to resolve this issue.

A possible solution is to implement `MockStore` as a `StoreType` and use `Store` object to implement behavior for `StoreType` interface.

Comment: the issue is, you can't use `StoreType` as a specific type because of associatedtype inside

Comment: @VladHatko type erase it

Comment: yes, but for testing - I don't really see how you plan to use it. to substitude `Store` by `MockStore` you have to use var with type of `StoreType`, which you can't do because of the `associatedtype`. does that make sense?

Comment: @VladHatko that's the point of type erasure. You will have to subtype the `StoreType` with `MyStoreType` which will add a `func toAnyStore() -> AnyStoreType<YourAssociatedType>` and create a class `AnyStoreType<YourAssociatedType>` which takes `origin` and tunnels `StoreType` methods and use it as a dependency throughout the app.

Comment: @VladHatko that's how `RxSwift` does it for example

Comment: still don't understand you. what is `AnyStoreType` in your code?

Comment: @VladHatko `AnyStoreType<State: StateType>: MyStoreType` and `protocol MyStoreType: StoreType { func toAnyStore() -> AnyStoreType<State> }`. Now for every concrete `MyStoreType` you create, you also have to provide such type erasure, and the users of your concrete implementation will only accept `AnyStoreType` as a dependency.

Comment: Here is a simple example on how type erasure can be used and implemented: https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/

Comment: But I would highly suggest you to study how interaction between `Observable<E>`, `ObservableType` and different concrete implementations such as `PublishSubject` is implemented in `RxSwift`. It will provide you with a valuable insight on how to work around the absence of generic protocols in Swift.